# Нужна ли запятая: "В маленьком домике на берегу реки, вдали от Москвы"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужная ли запятая перед "вдали".

> Моя бабушка живет в маленьком домике на берегу реки, вдали от Москвы

Comment: Не река, а бабушка живёт вдали от Москвы, что с запятой, что без неё. Но лучше первый вариант, т. е. с запятой. А без запятой лучше переместить "вдали" ближе к бабушке: "Моя бабушка живет вдали от Москвы в маленьком домике на берегу реки".
О реке же следует позаботиться особо: "Моя бабушка живет в маленьком домике на берегу реки, текущей вдали от Москвы".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и примеры.

Comment: Hermit, последний Ваш вариант не годится, поскольку её бабушка может жить на берегу реки в том месте, которое далеко от Москвы, а сама река длинная и может протекать рядом с Москвой.

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от вкладываемого смысла.
Если важно подчеркнуть, что река вдали от Москвы, то запятая не нужна.
Если же река здесь столь важна, а смысл тот, что бабушка живет а) на берегу реки б) в маленьком домике и в) вдали от Москвы, то одна, а то и две, запятая возможна - и даже желательна. Мне кажется, второе толкование более вероятно. Поэтому я бы эту запятую сохранил.

Хотя это личное мнение. У меня в подобных случаях частые разногласия с профессионалами.

Comment: Т.е. на Ваш взгляд возможны вообще три варианта: без запятых, с одной запятой, с двумя запятыми?

Comment: Странно, обычно я сразу отвечаю на вопросы.  Да, возможны три варианта.  "В маленьком домике, на берегу реки, вдали от Москвы" вполне тянут на однородные обстоятельства. Для этого, конечно, нужно особое авторское виденье текста, но грамматике не противоречит.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу здесь уточнения, поэтому запятая не нужна. Река находится вдали от Москвы

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если река находится не вдали от Москвы? Реки ведь длинные бывают. (Я сейчас рассматриваю не географическое положение). Или взять другой пример: "Бабушка жила в маленьком домике на берегу моря, вдали от Ялты". Это ведь не значит, что Ялта находится вдали от моря. И Ялта, и бабушкин домик находятся на одном побережье, просто на большом расстоянии друг от друга.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите сказать, что река находится вдали от Москвы, то предложение желательно перестроить, например так:

**Моя бабушка живет в маленьком домике на берегу реки, протекающей вдали от Москвы**

А в исходном виде интонация такова, что становится ясно — предложение сообщает нам два факта: 1) бабушка живет в маленьком домике на берегу реки, 2) бабушка живет вдали от Москвы. Такое сообщение требует запятой:

**Моя бабушка живет в маленьком домике на берегу реки, вдали от Москвы.**